# How to write documents like YUI user guides?

Tags: yui

YUI user guides are really nice, please visit http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/ for example,I just wanna write documents like that. My question is:  these documents were generated by some tools like Dockbook,Sphix or written by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YUI User Guides are generated from Mustache templates using a tool called **Selleck**. Selleck is a Node.js tool that generates pages from different templates based on the information provided in a `component.json` file and a predefined folder structure. One of the coolest features of this tool is that it has a `--server` mode which runs a local web server in which you can see the changes you made live by just refreshing the page.

You can check it out at http://yui.github.com/selleck/.